# Detect Url in other apps webview

Tags: android

From my app (That has accessibility permission),
I'm looking for a way to detect the urls that are loaded on other apps webview's.
For exmple:
in the gmail app if a user clickes a link in opens inside the gmail app.
I would like to have a way to know the page url.

Thanks
Avi

Comment: Fortunately, Android makes it difficult to detect the URLs that are loaded on other apps' `WebView` widgets (or any other use of URLs, such as for Web service communications). Outside of a `VpnService`, this shouldn't be possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare so its difficult but not impossible.

Comment: What if my app has accessibility permission?